# Why CombineByKey error appears when using 3 elements tuples?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to work on scala in order to calculate some statistics on my data.
I have An array of tuples

```
agency_time_map = Array(("LA", 2), ("NY", 4), ...)
```

I am trying trying to use CombineByKey:

```
val combiner = (x: Double) => (1, x, x*x)

val merger = (x: (Int, Double, Double), y: (Double, Double)) => {
    val (c, acc_1, acc_2) = x
    val (y_1, y_2) = y
    (c+1, acc_1 + y_1, acc_2 + y_2)
}

val mergeAndCombiner = (x1: (Int, Double, Double), x2: (Int, Double, Double)) => {
    val (c1, acc1_1, acc1_2) = x1
    val (c2, acc2_1, acc2_2) = x2
    (c1+c2, acc1_1 + acc2_1, acc1_2 + acc2_2)
}
```

I get the following error when using it on my data:

```
agency_time_map.combineByKey(combiner,merger,mergeAndCombiner)

<console>:32: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ((Int, Double, Double), (Double, Double)) => (Int, Double, Double)
 required: (?, Double) => ?
       agency_time_map.combineByKey(combiner,merger,mergeAndCombiner)
```

I have been trying to figure it our but the interpretation of the error is quite difficult.

I suspect the problem coming either from the combiner or the merger method.

Could you help me figure out the issue?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the type of `agency_time_map` and spark version you are using. Also see [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to write questions easier to read/understand.

Comment: Hi shanmuga, I modified my post to answer your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because [signature of combine by key, define in context of  `RDD[(K, V)]` is](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions@combineByKey[C](createCombiner:V=%3EC,mergeValue:(C,V)=%3EC,mergeCombiners:(C,C)=%3EC):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,C)])

> `def combineByKey[C](createCombiner: (V) ⇒ C, mergeValue: (C, V) ⇒ C, mergeCombiners: (C, C) ⇒ C): RDD[(K, C)]`

This means that the type of the second argument of `mergeValue` - `V`

```
mergeValue: (C, V) ⇒ C
```

has to match the second type of the argument and the type of the argument of `createCombiner`.

If `createCombiner` is defined as

```
val combiner = (x: Double) => (1, x, x*x)
```

which is `(Double) => (Int, Double Double)` then `mergeValue` has to be:

```
(C, Double) => C
```

where `C` is `(Int, Double Double)` - return type of `createCombiner`.

This *obviously* is not satisfied if `createCombiner` is  `(C, (Double, Double)) => C` as in your code.

Let's leave the actual implementation as an exercise for the user - as the question looks far to close to be homework assignment.

Comment: Thank you so much.